# How do I access files from another computer connected over LAN?

Tags: vb.net, networking, file-transfer

Can anyone provide the resource to learn making connection between computers over the LAN and retrieve files?

EDIT:
And can I browse the folders like its done in the local machine?

Comment: If it's on a share, then the comments below will help you out. Otherwise, could you provide some more information? Do you want to FTP files? Or do you want to send a file from one application to another?

Comment: I would like to open a word document from another computer. And I was told that wpf doesnt allow ms doc's and instead xps are used. Any input regarding that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim f As FileStream = File.Open("\\server\folder\subfolder\file.txt",FileMode.Open)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the UNC path.  The other computer should have a folder shared.

> \\OtherComputerName\SharedFolderName\FileYouWantName.txt

Use that path in vb to open/read the file just as you would a local path.

Answer (score 1):

If the document is on a share on the other computer, you can use the other answers (the UNC path: \server\share\file.doc). WPF does focus support on XPS files, but if you want to open a Word file in your application, maybe check out [this post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WordToXps09242009101005AM/WordToXps.aspx).

If you just want to launch Word and open the file, you'll have to check out the Office Interop assemblies. Something like this should work (I haven't tested this myself though):

```
Dim wordApplication As New Word.Application
Dim document As New Word.Document

document = wordApplication .Documents.Open("\\server\share\file.doc")
```